# Re-create hard deleted stream

Tags: event-sourcing, eventstoredb

I have accidentally hard-deleted a stream from [EventStore](https://eventstore.org/docs/introduction/) using `ES-HardDelete` in request header. When I am trying to create it again it fails with `410 Permanently Deleted`.

I tried deleting the EventStore db and log folder. No luck. Also tried deleting entire EventStore and installing fresh one, still it fails to create the same stream.

Is there any way so that I can create the stream with same name again?